# Google Play Developer Console: grant read access to single app

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible in the Google Play Developer Console to grant READ ONLY access to a user for a single application?

By default, if a new user is added to the account and no permissions are granted, the new user gets read access to ALL applications.

Note that I am not asking about how to grant the various writing permissions on a per-app basis: I am asking about how to remove the reading permission for all apps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<strike>Old question but the accepted answer is incorrect, perhaps outdated.</strike>

When inviting a new user, deselect all permissions from the 'global' column, and then using the drop-down list to add columns for individual apps you can add specific permissions for specific apps.

For example, you can give only read access for only one app, which I believe is what you would like to do.

Comment: I have tested this btw, the invited email account is unable to see the apps for which it was not given any permissions

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no way to limit the invited user's right to view your other listings in the Google Play Developer Console. The only rights you can customize are the following:

- Create & edit draft apps
- Edit store listing, pricing & distribution
- Manage Production APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta APKs
- Manage Alpha & Beta users
- View financial reports
- Reply to reviews
- Edit games
- Publish games

Reference: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2528691

Comment: Thanks for confirming this. I knew the reference document, which is a bit confusing as it states: "If you want to restrict the user to a specific app, leave permissions unchecked. You can add app specific rights after you've sent an invitation."

Answer (score 0):

Once you invite someone with no permissions, there is a settings button next to their invitation. From there you can give specific app permissions.

[image]

[image]

Then...

Comment: thank you but this is not what I was asking about:

"Note that I am not asking about how to grant the various writing permissions on a per-app basis: I am asking about how to remove the reading permission for all apps."